# Install Ubuntu on Android tablet and nuke Android OS

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-touch, flash, android, tablet

I have a android table with a 1.7ghz processor and 512mb ram
I want to nuke Android and install whatever version of Ubuntu would run smoothly in these conditions.
Anybody got a step by step on this. Must still be able to use my bluetooth keyboard and mouse and the usb port.

Comment: Absolutely want to nuke android! will not waste precious cpu cycles on that garbage! xD

Comment: Ubuntu Touch recommends that your device has 1GB RAM.

Answer (score 3):

I was once looking at doing this myself, but it wasn't guarenteed to work, depending on what model and spec of your tablet is. XDA Developers forums had quite a few devs trying out different custom ROMs to get Ubuntu to install and very few were successful, so you may want to head over there and read through what they tried.

Since Ubuntu has already announced the support of Ubuntu on tablet in there Ubuntu Touch releases, I'd recommend checking that out. Currently there are two stable releases for the Nexus 4 and Nexus Galaxy. I think karel might be right that Ubuntu would require more resources then your tablet could spare, so you may have some work and research yet to be done. Link to Ubuntu Touch below.

[Ubuntu Touch Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install)